# What is the best implementation of pagination using Apollo hooks in a react native flatlist?

Tags: react-native, apollo, apollo-client

Im looking for insight on how best to implement a loadMore function in the onEndReached callback provided by flatlist while using apollo hooks! I've got it sort of working except every time i load more results the list jumps to the top since the data field of flatlist relies on incoming data from useQuery that changes every time it asks for more...
I dont know if i should be implementing offset and limit based pagination, cursor based, or some other strategy.
If anyone has tips that would be huge! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Shopify storefront graphql queries to get product list, and here is how I have implemented pagination using cursor-based pagination method on FlatList. Hope you find something usable.

First, declare two variables which will be used later to check whether the Flatlist scrolled and reached on the end.

```js
// declare these two variables
let isFlatlistScrolled = false;
let onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;
```

Now, create a method called `handleFlatlistScroll` which will be used to changed the values of the variable `isFlatlistScrolled` when the flatlist is scrolled.

```js
const handleFlatlistScroll = () => {
  isFlatlistScrolled = true;
};
```

Also declare a method to change the value of `onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum`.

```js
const onMomentumScrollBegin = () => {
  onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false;
}
```

Now, create your flatlist like this :

```js
return (
  <Layout style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Query
      query={GET_PRODUCT_LIST_BY_COLLECTION_HANDLE}
      variables={{
        handle: props.route.params.handle,
        cursor: null,
      }}>
      {({
        loading,
        error,
        data,
        fetchMore,
        networkStatus,
        refetch,
        stopPolling,
      }) => {
        if (loading) {
          return <ProductListPlaceholder />;
        }
        if (data && data.collectionByHandle?.products?.edges?.length > 0) {
          stopPolling();
          return (
            <FlatList
              data={data.collectionByHandle.products.edges}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.node.id}
              renderItem={renderProductsItem}
              initialNumToRender={20}
              onScroll={handleFlatlistScroll}
              onEndReached={() => {
                if (
                  !onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum &&
                  isFlatlistScrolled &&
                  !isLoadingMoreProducts &&
                  !loading &&
                  data.collectionByHandle?.products?.pageInfo?.hasNextPage
                ) {
                  onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
                  setLoadingMoreProductsStatus(true);
                  // your loadmore function to fetch more products
                }
              }}
              onEndReachedThreshold={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0.1}
              onMomentumScrollBegin={onMomentumScrollBegin}
              // ... your other flatlist props
            />
          );
        }
        return <EmptyProductList />;
      }}
    </Query>
  </Layout>
)
```

As you can see in above code, load more function only called when flatlist is properly scrolled at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the input! How are you handling the merging of new results? When i load new items my flatlist rerenders because the data prop changes...

Comment: It based on which data you are rendering flatlist. I using an apollo query which returns data variable, so I am just concateing new return with that data. You can also concate new data with the current one.